# Magento:Upload file in ajax form

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have a custom frontend form. The form is submitted via ajax. The form has a **"type=file"** field. I want to save the uploaded file to a folder.How can I do that. Please help..

How is it possible to get the uploaded file in ajax sumbitted form

This is my "type=file" field in phtml.

```
<div class="input-box">
    <label for="addfile"><?php echo $this->__('Select File(s)');?></label><br />
    <p>Upload any files that are necessary for your order by clicking on the Add File(s) button below.</p>
    <input type="file" class="file" id="attachment" name="attachement" style="display: none;" onchange="fileSelected(this)" value=""/>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="btnAttachment" onclick="openAttachment()" value="Add File(s)"/>
</div>
```

This is my button field in phtml.(button action is file upload)

```
<div>
    <input type="button" class="button" id="btnUpload" onclick="callAjax()" value="Upload File(s)"/>
</div>
```

This is my script

```
function callAjax(){
    var filename = document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML;//alert(test);
    var companyname = document.getElementById("company").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("f_name").value+" "+document.getElementById("l_name").value;
    var phnumber = document.getElementById("phnmbr").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var file = document.getElementById("select-file-det").innerHTML;
     jQuery.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/index/action'); ?>",
        data    : ({company: companyname,name: name,phnumber: phnumber,email:email,file: file,filename:filename }),
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function(response) {   
           document.getElementById("success-msg").style.display = "block"; 
           document.getElementById("select-file-form").style.display = "none"; 
           //setTimeout(function() { window.location=window.location;},3000);           
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try:**

```
function callAjax(){

     jQuery.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/index/action'); ?>",
        data: jQuery('form').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
           document.getElementById("success-msg").style.display = "block"; 
           document.getElementById("select-file-form").style.display = "none";                          
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: The button type is not submit. I have added the code. Please see edited question

Comment: @E.B check my updated answer

Comment: I have tried this method. But i got all field values except the input type="file" field

Comment: @E.B You need to add enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form.

Answer (score 0):

1. First  You need to Select image file through following line of html code

   ```
   input type="file" id="image_to_upload"
   ```
2. After that you need to write the following jQuery code to catch this event.

```
    jQuery.noConflict();    
    formdata = new FormData();      
    jQuery("#image_to_upload").on("change", function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        if (formdata) {
            formdata.append("image", file);
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "destination_ajax_file.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success:function(){}
            });
        }                       
    });
```

3. In the destination ajax file you can access image by the following variable

```
print_r($_FILES);
```